# Which one is right: "My dream has started ~" or "My dream was started ~"?

Tags: tense, verbs, grammaticality-in-context

1. > My dream has started by ~
2. > My dream was started by ~

I want to know which one is the correct one.

Comment: @CopperKettle You should use either "is" or "constructions" in the last sentence. I am not sure what you are trying to ask the OP by asking "How do we call this construction?".

Comment: @Rathony - I hoped Jason would recall that *has started* is a Present Perfect construction, and *was started* is a passive voice construction. Maybe the proper question is "what do we call this construction?" or "how do we classify such constructions" or "what is the tense used here" or whatever.

Comment: Please write full sentences, context and your research/reference in the question. Otherwise, it is not easy to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*My dream **has started** by* employs a **present perfect active** construction.

- As a present perfect this designates a present state which arose out of the past event. For instance, if I say "I have started", I signal that the necessary preliminaries of some activity are complete and I am now free to move to the next step.
- Because it is an active construction, the dream itself is treated as the "agent" of the action—your dream started on its own. A *by* phrase  following an active *START* therefore will not designate the agent. It might be a locative ("We will start by the river and move uphill from there"), but it is more likely to take as its object a gerund designating the first action taken by the agent, the action which constituted the start. For instance, I might at this point in this answer say

  > I have started by describing the grammatical meaning of a present perfect active predicate modified with a *by* phrase.

  That specifies the start more precisely; you now understand that the "present state" designated by the present perfect is that you understand the grammatical
  meaning which I have described.

It's difficult, however, to imagine a scenario in which it would make sense to speak of a *dream* starting by doing something. It is far more likely that you mean *My dream **was started** by*, employing a **past passive** form.

- The past form designates a past event; it says only that the event occurred, without implying any current state.
- In the passive construction the subject is the "patient" of the action—something else started your dream. A *by* phrase following a passive construction usually designates the "agent", the 'something else' which actually performed the action.

  > My dream of mastering English was started by my teacher Mr. Robinson.
  >   My dream of mastering English was started by my obsession with 1930s Hollywood gangster movies.
  >   My dream of mastering English was started by my observing that people who speak English get into better schools.

Comment: Great answer. As a footnote, I think we could use "my dream has started" if we rearrange the sentence, and leave out the "by such-and-such." For example: _I'm a registered freshman, and classes start tomorrow. My dream of getting a college diploma has started!_